# AHCI - Will be two HDDs (SSDs) two times faster?

Tags: ssd, sata

Lets take common numbers:

```
SATA HDD - 120Mb/s read, write speed heavily depends on gaps in sequence
SATA SSD - 550Mb/s read, 500Mb/s write
PCIe SSD - 2500Mb/s read, 1500Mb/s write
```

Lets assume they are connected to AHCI controller (not RAID controller). If we connect two identical drives to AHCI (not RAID-0) and use two-threaded application running on two CPU cores to read/write sequental data, will be speed doubled?

Comment: theoretically yes, practical anything from actually beeing slower to nearly close to 2x the speed is possible.

Comment: Very likely true, if your application is well written for that situation.

Answer (score 2):

> will be speed doubled?

Yes, No, Maybe - anywhere in between - it entirely depends on the actual configuration and the nature of the use case. In real terms yes you should see *some* benefit but the only way to know is to test it as you need.